# Difference between using Wrapper at root level and using Wrapper inside a HOC (Nextjs)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In the nextjs application I had two ways to pass the data needed by one page(route) only

I had two options

1. Using Wapper at _app.ts

```
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import Head from "next/head";
import {ContextProvider} from "@/provider"
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "@/store";

function App(props: AppProps) {
  const {
    Component,
    pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
  } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width"
        />
      </Head>
      {/* <Layout> */}
      <Provider store={store}>
      <ContextProvider>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ContextProvider>
      </Provider>
      {/* </Layout> */}
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

2. Wrapping the one page component

```
import React from 'react'

type Props = {}

const ID = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>ID</div>
  )
}

export default withProvider(ID)
```

withProvider.tsx

```
import {SocketContextProvider} from "./Context";

const withProvider = (PageComponent) => {
  const WrappedPage = (props: any) => (
    <SocketContextProvider>
      <PageComponent {...props} />
    </SocketContextProvider>
  );

  return WrappedPage;
};

export default withProvider;
```

Does one method has edge over the other if the application needs continuous change in Context Data